# How to insert a variable value at the end of each list using flex?

Tags: regex, lex, flex-lexer

The raw sample data looks something like this:

```
neg      
test  
-1.0 1.0    
-2.1 3.45
```

and i have to convert it using flex into a recognized ocaml input list like this:

```
let test  
=[  
[ -1.0 ; 1.0 ; 1.0; -1.0 ];  
[ -2.1 ; 3.45 ; 1.0; -1.0 ]  
];;
```

I'm able to convert it as follows:

```
let test  
=[  
[ -1.0 ; 1.0 ; 1.0 ; ]; 
[ -2.1 ; 3.45 ; 1.0 ; ]
];;
```

The main question that i have is:

> 1. How to put the last element in each list as -1 if raw data says neg and as 1 if raw data says pos?

Comment: what's your code? how did you arrive at this result?

Comment: I'm not familiar with flex but I know that this is not possible in regular expressions; as I've argued many times before, you cannot magically make characters appear via substitution, if those characters didn't appear in the original text to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add some form of parsing. Look into Bison for this, it integrates well with flex. So you get some rules looking something like this.

```
let_expression: "neg" identifier vector_list
{
//Finalize by printing stored data and add -1
}
              |  identifier vector_list
{
//Finalize by printing stored data and add 1
}

vector_list: vector_list vector
{
  //Store your number pairs in a std::vector<std::pair<T,T>>
}
           | vector
{
  //Initialize the vector list.
}

vector: const_num const_num
{
  //Store your numbers, maybe in a std::pair
  $$ = std::make_pair($1,$2)
}
```

Comment: Well I'm only allowed to use flex for this and not bison. I'm still not sure how to do this using flex.

Comment: Why are you only allowed to use flex?